# Convergence of a Dirichlet series

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series

For a fixed positive integer $j$, consider the arithmetical function :

$$\vartheta _{j}(k+1)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \;\;, & k+1=j^{l}\;\;(l=1,2,3...)\\ 
0 \;\;, & \text{otherwise} 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
We construct the Dirichlet series :
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left | G_{m+1} \right |\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{k}\binom{m}{k}\frac{\vartheta _{j}(k+1)}{(k+1)^{s}}$$
Where $|G_{k}|$ is the kth [Gregory coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients), and $s\in\mathbb{C}$. Does this series converge, and if yes, what is its abscissa of convergence ?

Comment: I assume you mean $\vartheta_{m}(k+1)$ instead of $\vartheta_{j}(k+1)$ in the Dirichlet series?

Comment: No, the index is fixed, and it's $j$.

Comment: For the case $j=1$ the variable $s$ drops out and the Dirichlet series evaluates to $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\left| \frac{1}{(m+1)!}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m+1}\frac{S_{m+1}^{(l)}}{l+1}\right|=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{(m+1)!}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m+1} \frac{S_{m+1}^{(l)}}{l+1}$ which I believe converges to a constant (perhaps $1$?). I suspect for $j>1$ you may get different answers for different values of $j$.

Comment: All of the nonzero terms have the same sign $(-1)^{j-1}$ when $s$ is real, and so one can rearrange the terms arbitrarily; I think it's not hard to see that the sum over $m$ diverges for every real $s$ (and hence for every $s\in\Bbb C$ by general Dirichlet series facts).